# Commiting issues with SVN X

Tags: svn, osx-lion

I have a problem with my SVN X. I made a commit into my svn server, and added an old version of my XCode project file (.xcodeproj file). Now when I try to commit changes, the SVN server tells me that I need to update my project. I've updated the project but the .xcodeproj file seems corrupted, so I replaced it with another one that I manually backed up, but when I try to commit again, the server returns the same message.

I'm using the same revision that the server has, so I don't see why SVN can't overwrite the file.

Any hints, or help would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you commit, it doesn't mean that your code is up-to-date.  Run

```
svn update
```

To bump up your local copies of revision numbers, then you will likely be able to proceed as normal.

I've noticed that this happens a bit more often when one commits just a few files, but that might just be me.

Comment: it works!! I guess that I'll switch back to console, SVN on Mac is quite bad using SVN X, I'm used to Tortoise... Thanks a lot!